# Datepicker Input in Lightning Web Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I want to any pass date value from Datepicker input of lightning web component to PostingDate variable in LWCcontroller.cls

```js
import { LightningElement,api ,track} from 'lwc';

import getInvoiceData from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerRefundLwcController.getInvoiceData';
import getBankAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerRefundLwcController.getBankAccounts';
import processCustomerRefund from '@salesforce/apex/CustomerRefundLwcController.processCustomerRefund';

export default class CustomerRefund extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; /*Sales Credit Id*/
    @track invoiceData;
    @track invoiceLinesData;
    @api headerText;
    @api recordProcessing;
    @api bankAccounts = new Array();
    @track selectedBankId;
    @track allocateToSalesCredit;
    @track referenceDetail;
    @track bShowModal = false;
    @track PostingDate;
    /*Toast Event Variables*/
    @api isError = false;
    @api iswarning = false;
    @api issuccess = false;
    @api ToastMessage;

PostingDateChange(event)
    {
        this.PostingDate = event.target.value;
        this.invoiceData.PostingDate = this.PostingDate;
    }
    
     processRefundHandler() {
        this.recordProcessing = true;
        //console.log('this.formData----'+JSON.stringify(this.invoiceLinesData));
        console.log('this.formData----'+JSON.stringify(this.invoiceData));
        processCustomerRefund({ lstInvoiceLines : this.invoiceLinesData, bankId : this.selectedBankId, allocateToSalesCredit : this.allocateToSalesCredit, reference : this.referenceDetail, postingdate : this.PostingDate })
        .then(result => {
            var responseMessage = result;
            this.recordProcessing = false;
            
            this.ToastMessage = responseMessage;
            if(responseMessage == "Success"){
                //this.issuccess = true;
                this.isError = false;
                this.ToastMessage = "Your Bank Customer Refund has been created";
                this.bShowModal = true;
            }else{
                this.isError = true;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.isError = true;
            this.ToastMessage = error ;
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

```html
<div class="slds-col"> 
            
            <label class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex">Posting Date</label>
            <lightning-input type="date" 
                        name="Postingdate" 
                        value={PostingDate}
                        onchange={PostingDateChange}
            >
            </lightning-input>  
         
        </div>
```

CRLWC.cls
@AuraEnabled
public static string processCustomerRefund(List lstInvoiceLines,string bankId,boolean allocateToSalesCredit,string reference){
system.debug('start update');
string successMessage = 'Success';
string responseMessage = 'Success';
Savepoint spTran = database.setSavePoint();
try{
List<Sales_Invoice_Line_Item__c> lstLinesToUpdate = new List<Sales_Invoice_Line_Item__c>();
decimal amount=0;
Id taxRate;
Id salesinvoiceid;

```
        boolean isValid = true;
        boolean allocateToInvoice = allocateToSalesCredit;
        map<id,Sales_Invoice_Line_Item__c> mapOfSelectedLines = new map<id,Sales_Invoice_Line_Item__c>();

        for(ScLineWrapper lineWrapper : lstInvoiceLines){
            system.debug('isselect>> ' + lineWrapper.isSelected);
            if(lineWrapper.isSelected){
                salesinvoiceid = lineWrapper.InvoiceLine.Sales_Invoice__c;
                decimal lineAmount = lineWrapper.InvoiceLine.Foreign_Gross__c;
                if(lineAmount != null && lineAmount > 0){
                    amount += lineAmount;
                    mapOfSelectedLines.put(lineWrapper.InvoiceLine.id,lineWrapper.InvoiceLine);
                }

                if(lineWrapper.InvoiceLine.Tax_Rate__c != null){
                    taxRate = lineWrapper.InvoiceLine.Tax_Rate__c;
                }
            }
        }

        if(salesinvoiceid == null){
            isValid = false;
            responseMessage = 'Please select at least one sales invoice line';
        }else if(bankId == null){
            isValid = false;
            responseMessage = 'Please select bank account';
        }else if(amount <= 0){
            isValid = false;
            responseMessage = 'Refund amount should be greater than zero';
        }

        system.debug('updatelst>> ' + lstLinesToUpdate);
        //update lstLinesToUpdate;
        if(isValid){
            Sales_Invoice__c siInfo = [select id,Status__c,Account__c,Name from Sales_Invoice__c where id=: salesinvoiceid];
            BankCustomerRefundService objCustomerRefundService = new BankCustomerRefundService();
            BankCustomerRefundService.BankCustomerRefundWrapper objRefundWrapper = new BankCustomerRefundService.BankCustomerRefundWrapper();
            Id accountId = siInfo.Account__c;
            objRefundWrapper.AccountId = accountId;
            objRefundWrapper.PostingDate = Date.Today()+(-216);
            objRefundWrapper.BankAccountId = bankId;
            objRefundWrapper.TaxRate = taxRate;
            objRefundWrapper.Amount = amount;
            objRefundWrapper.Reference = reference;
            BankCustomerRefundService.Response objResponse = objCustomerRefundService.CreateBankCustomerRefund(objRefundWrapper);
            responseMessage = objResponse.ResponseMessage;

            if(allocateToInvoice && responseMessage == successMessage){
                Bank_Payment__c objBankPayment = objResponse.BankPayments.get(accountId);
                List<Ledger__c> listofLedgers = [Select id,name,Foreign_Gross_Total__c,Type__c
                                                FROM Ledger__c
                                                Where Customer_Supplier_Account_Name__c =: accountId AND Show_On_Transaction__c=1
                                                AND Paid__c = 'N' AND Is_Deleted__c = false
                                                AND (Sales_Invoice_Line_Item__c IN: mapOfSelectedLines.keyset() OR Bank_Payment__c =: objBankPayment.id) ];
                
                if(!listofLedgers.isEmpty()){
                    BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService objAllocateCreditsAndPaymentService = new BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService();
                    BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsWrapper objAllocateCreditWrapper = new BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsWrapper();
                    objAllocateCreditWrapper.AccountId = accountId;
                    objAllocateCreditWrapper.PostingDate = Date.Today()+(-216);
                    List<BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLineWrapper> BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLines = new List<BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLineWrapper>();
                    for(Ledger__c ledger : listofLedgers){
                        BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLineWrapper objPaymentLine = new BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLineWrapper();
                        objPaymentLine.LedgerName = ledger.Name;
                        objPaymentLine.Amount = ledger.Foreign_Gross_Total__c;
                        BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLines.add(objPaymentLine);
                    }

                    objAllocateCreditWrapper.BankAllocateLines = BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsLines;
                    BankAllocateCreditsAndPaymentsService.Response objAllocateResponse = objAllocateCreditsAndPaymentService.BankAllocateCustomerBalance(objAllocateCreditWrapper);
                    responseMessage = objAllocateResponse.ResponseMessage;
                    system.debug('Response>>' + objAllocateResponse.ResponseMessage);
                }                                                    
            }
            
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        responseMessage = ex.getStackTraceString();
    }
    
    if(responseMessage != successMessage){
        Database.rollback(spTran);
    }
    system.debug('Response>>' + responseMessage);
    return responseMessage;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new parameter `postingdate` to the Apex Method

```java
@AuraEnabled 
public static string processCustomerRefund (
    List lstInvoiceLines,
    String bankId,
    Boolean allocateToSalesCredit,
    String reference,
    Long postingdate
) {
```

I'm not sure long is the correct type thought, maybe DateTime or Date, I don't remember how Salesforce handle this. If it's long, it would be a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Lightning input (type="date") returns a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.
Here's what I did:

```cs
public static Date convertDate(String datestr){
    List<String> dateSplit = datestr.split('-');
    return Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[0]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[1]), Integer.valueOf(dateSplit[2]));
}
```

You could also simply use `Date` as a parameter type in the apex method and that should work as well.